# What qualifies as a polynomial?

Tags: functions, polynomials, definition, real-numbers

I have a very simple question regarding the definition of polynomials (with real coefficients).

What I've seen so far in terms of defintions:

1. A polynomial $p(x)$ is a function that can be written in the form $p(x)=\sum^n_{k=0} a_kx^k$ where $a_k$ are real numbers.
2. A polynomial is an expression involving only addition, subtraction, multiplication and integer exponents.

Now $f(x) = (2x-1)(3x + 4)$ is a polynomial so the representation $\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx^k$ is not essential. Of course one can rewrite $f$ in the desired form.  If I have, say, the function
$$
p(x)=\frac{x^3-x^2+x-1}{x^2+1}
$$
then this is not a polynomial as it stands. However one can easily represent it as a polynomial by factoring out $x^2 + 1$. Another example that I wonder about is the function
$$
q(x)=\begin{cases} x^2+1 & \text{if } x>0 \\ x + 1 & \text{if } x \le 0\end{cases}
$$
The latter involves only the allowed operations, furthermore pointwise it is of the form $\sum_k^n a_kx^k$.

So my question is whether the examples $p$ and $q$ above are polynomials, and if not -- what is the precise definition of a polynomial ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $(2x-1)(3x+4)$ is a function that can be written in the form you want, so it qualifies as a polynomial with the first definition as well.

Comment: @Macavity yes I think so as well, that's why I took it as an illustrative example to contrast the other functions  $p$ and $q$. These can also be written in the form I want however I would not say that they are polynomials.

Comment: Well unless you specify the function is valid for all reals, any definition can be made piece wise valid. So it seems as good as any other definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A polynomial is usually not considered as a function, which is a key distinction, though you can **use** a polynomial to **define** a function.  When we have a polynomial in a variable $x$, $x$ is frequently called an *indeterminate*.  This means that it is a symbol, not a number.  The way we get a function from a polynomial is called *evaluation*; it is the act of putting in specific real numbers in replacement of the indeterminate $x$.  But this is usually considered something we can *do* with a polynomial, and the polynomial itself is not thought of as a function.

We can multiply polynomials to get new polynomials (you just distribute through to get the $a_{i}$ needed to represent it in the form you give), but division by terms involving $x$ is not allowed.
For example, $(2x-1)(3x+4) = 6x^{2}+5x-4$ is a polynomial, but
$$\frac{x^{3}-x^{2}+x-1}{x^{2}+1}$$
is **not** a polynomial.  You are correct that we could do some cancellation to get a polynomial, the technical term here is that the *function* defined by this formula can be written as a *polynomial* function (or we would say that once we do some cancellation, we have a polynomial).

The piecewise function you gave is also not a polynomial; it involves one extra operation that is not allowed, which is essential the "conditional" part of the statement (that decides which formula to use).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is enough to be expressible in the form $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^ka_ix^i$ for some $k\geq0$ and $a_i\in\Bbb{R}$. This expression should hold for *all* $x\in\Bbb{R}$. So for example, your function
$$p(x)=\frac{x^3-x^2+x-1}{x^2+1},$$
is a real polynomial, because $p(x)=x-1$ holds for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. But $p(x)$ isn't a complex polynomial because it isn't defined at $\pm i$.

Answer (score 0):

We would need to define a polynomial.

A polynomial in terms of $x_1, x_2,...x_n$ is a particular type of mathematical expression with the following restriction:

The $x_i$s are only added , subtracted , multiplied , or raised to positive integer powers. If an $x_i$ is subject to any other operation, it is not a polynomial **in terms of that particular $x_i$**

- $x$ is a polynomial in terms of $x$, a monomial to be precise.
- $x$-1 is also a polynomial (binomial) in terms of $x$
- $x^2-f$ is also a polynomial in terms of $x$
- $3x^3-2x^2+x-7$ is a polynomial in terms of $x$.

Here are some expressions that are **not** polynomials in terms of $x$

- $2^x$, because this expression takes the antilog of $x$ to the base
  2
- $x^{-\pi}$, because $-\pi$ is not a positive integer.
- $\frac1x$, because it equals $x^{-1}$, and $-1$ is not a positive
  integer.
- $\log(x)$, because $x$ is either the base or the subject of the
  common    logarithm function.

Of course, polynomials can be in more than one variable.

$x_1{x_2}^2+{x_3}^5$ is a polynomial in terms of all $x_1, x_2$, and $x_3$

$x_1^2-\frac{x_2}{x_3}$, is only a polynomial in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$, because $x_3$ is a divisor.

${x_1}^{x_2}-{x_3}^{-2}+x_1(\sin(x_4))$ is only a polynomial in terms of $x_1$